# How to keep fieldManager in Stack

Tags: blackberry

When i put a VerticalFieldManager to a Stack and delete all items in VerticalFieldManager, the VerticalFieldManager in Stack is also changing.

Does Stack keep reference of object? If so, how can I keep managers in a Stack?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish by using a Stack with your Managers? And yeah, the Stack maintains references to the object, it doesn't make a copy of it.

Comment: I am just trying to build a dynamic application. Layouts and items come from an XML. So i got many screens which users switch to another screen. And i thought that before switching anoter screen if i put fieldManagers of the current screen to a stack, then i can get it when user wants to go back.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Stack keep reference of object?

Yes, it works as any other Java container, such as a `Vector` for example.

> If so, how can I keep managers in a Stack?

Not sure what are you talking about. Once you have put an `Object` into container the `Object` is already kept by the container.

Probably say what are you trying to achieve with putting managers in a `Stack`.

Comment: I am using an XML document which contains information about layout of application and fields that layout have. So i created a verticalFieldManager and put fields in it according to XML. When application need to switch to another page, i want to keep current layout, then clear all items in it and replace new items according to XML data.

Could you offer another usefull way to achieve this dynamic pages issue?

Comment: @user696371: If I get you correctly, you are trying to optimize the performance (parse XML only once; use the same set of Fields on several screens). I would not do this unless I'm 100% sure the performance of this part requires optimization. Instead I'd start with a simple approach when each screen is created from zero (including parsing XML, fields instantiation, etc.).

Comment: You are right, it is really hard to manage fields by this way. I will think about your suggestion, thank you.